# How to simulate from a step (simple function) hazard function?

Tags: survival, simulation, hazard, quantiles

I have a step hazard function $h(t)$ (a simple function that jumps at specific times and it is constant between those jumps). Something like:

[image: Example piecewise constant hazard function]

How can I simulate survival times from this hazard function? Is there a clever way for doing so?

I was thinking of using the probability integral transform, by solving
$$\exp\left[-\int_0^t h(s)ds \right] = u,
$$
where $u\sim U(0,1)$, but I started wondering if there is a more efficient way for simulating these times.

Comment: This [reference](https://www.demogr.mpg.de/papers/technicalreports/tr-2010-003.pdf) details the steps to simulate from a piecewise constant hazard function.

Comment: Thanks, @Xi'an.

Comment: This might help: https://adibender.github.io/pammtools/reference/rpexp.html?q=rpexp

Comment: @adibender Thanks.